# choice correct tool to open with png at ubuntu eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

i am using ubuntu eclipse to develop android.there are aa.png and b.9.png at drawable folder .when i double click aa.png or double clickb.9.png,it is not show the pic,it give me mess。i only open it :Press right key of the mouse click the pic and choice the Open with.it is very not convenience。how to setting the eclipse .i can click the png,it can choice the tool to open it.

i also have the xml:

```
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/aa" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

when i press CTRL to the @drawable/aa,it also not open the aa png,it give me not correct coding not a pic，how to solve it.

Edit: i  donot think this question is easy,i also donot think this site only programs,because there are many config device question. i have test many ubuntu eclipse,when i open a xml,if the xml include :
   
the aa may be a png pic ,or may be a xml. when i press ctrl+aa,it give me not correct coding.but at xp it can correct tool to open it. i do as @dandc87 to do,and config ubuntu eclipse  as xp eclipse,but ubuntu eclipse not open it correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can set default editors for files

Go to `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations`

From there you can add & edit programs (internal or external) for a file type.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu eclipse not add .png type,only default  .9.png type,so need add .png type and open methhod. Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations